# Spring Configuration Properties Not Working with Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

**(Using Spring boot 2.4.5)**

For setup, let's say we have:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.test")
@RefreshScope
public class SomeConfiguration {
    private boolean enableHatredOfSpringOnlySometimes = true;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

And lets say in my application-{env}.properties I include:
app.test.enableHatredOfSpringOnlySometimes = false;

At runtime, spring will correctly change the enableHatredOfSpringOnlySometimes to true, however, if I try and change the KV via consul, it **WILL NOT** work. The only way it will work is if I remove all references to enableHatredOfSpringOnlySometimes in application.properties.

There is a solution and it's to use a map which would look something like this:

```java
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.test")
@RefreshScope
public Map<String, Object> appTestProperties() {
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

This reads from application.properties AND will change via consul.

I am puzzled since I can use the map, but I would really like meta data and type safety for my keys.

It almost appears like once spring picks up the application.properties keys, it no longer provides the refresh scope capabilities, but I could be wrong - did not look deep into this.

I have tried the following

- Changing @Configuration to @Component (realistically this wouldn't do anything regardless)
- Changing the creation of the bean to @Bean and not @Configuration
- Changing the prefix (grasping at straws here)
- Removing the default values set.
- Changing from @ConfigurationProperties to @Value - still does not work